# What is meant by anonymous params? And why are they needed?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I have encounter a method of notifying kernel about char device:

```
int cdev_add(struct cdev *, dev_t, unsigned);
```

from `<linux/cdev.h>` and do not understand, how is possible to pass unnamed params (there are two without name - second and third). And even, the third argument `unsigned` has partial type (unsigned int? char? long? ...). I have read somewhere, it is for function overloading to "pick" the right constructor, but if so, shouldn't be declared more of these constructor in the header?(but there aren't), So how do I reference such params without names?

Comment: This is a function prototype. Parameter names in prototypes are optional.

Comment: When have you ever referenced parameters by name while *calling* a function? When defining it is another matter entirely.

Comment: That's a function prototype. Search the code base for `cdev_add` and you should find a full function definition which will have parameter names.

Comment: _"I have read somewhere, it is for function overloading to "pick" the right constructor"_ - I think you are mistaking C for C++.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I meant reference them in the body of function

Comment: @HristoIliev if they are optional, then in case of absence of them, how does the function handle their use in definition?

Comment: @Herdsman - What you posted is not the body of the function. It's not a function definition, only a declaration.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, so I am rectify my question. "How does function definition handles optional params and reference them in their absence?"

Comment: Function definitions always name formal parameters. It is in function **prototypes** where they are optional. C doesn't have optional arguments - that's a C++ feature.

Comment: Just because the **name** is optional in a declaration, doesn't mean the parameter itself is optional when calling the function. When you want to use `cdev_add`, you will always have to supply all parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ([from here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.10/source/include/linux/cdev.h#L29)):

```
int cdev_add(struct cdev *, dev_t, unsigned);
```

Is a function *declaration*. It specifies the type of the three parameters that the function takes and the return type: in this case the function returns an `int`, and takes as parameters a `struct cdev *`, a `dev_t` and an `unsigned`. This is usually done in header files (`.h`) which are later included in order to let the compiler know which types are handled and returned by the function.

The fact that there are no parameter names does ***not*** mean that parameters are optional. There is no such thing as "optional parameter" in C, the closest you can get is through [variadic arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html) (which can only be used at the end of the parameter list), but you'll have to define the entire behavior yourself. A valid function declaration can also specify the parameter names, but that's not required.

This ([from here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.10/source/fs/char_dev.c#L479)):

```
int cdev_add(struct cdev *p, dev_t dev, unsigned count)
{
    // ... body skipped for simplicity ...
    return 0;
}
```

Is a function *definition*. It must define all parameter names and the body of the function, containing the actual code.

Comment: There are optional parameters in C; functions declared with `...` may have varying numbers and types of arguments.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Those are not optional parameters, but variadic arguments. They can be used to implement optional parameters, but the language does not define any particular semantic for it. They can also only be used at the end of the parameter list. I guess it makes sense to mention it though.

Comment: still do not understand type `unsigned`  what kind of type that is? unsigned could be char, int , long, ..., almost every type in c could be unsigned (non negative). So it is partial type, not full type. how is that possible?

Comment: `unsigned` is a shorter way of writing `unsigned int`. Same goes for `long` which is `long int`, `long long`, `signed`, and `short`. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type).

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous (unnamed) parameters have two purposes:

- The first is that they don't need to be used in function prototypes, as the only purpose of a prototype is to inform the compiler of the number of parameters and the types of them to be used in the call.  In order to check if two prototypes are compatible (the same type) you have to check only the parameter order and the types of each parameter, but not the names, so if you put the prototypes with no parameter names, you can easily check the compatibility of functions.  The parameters are needed only in the function implementation, so they can be avoided in the prototype.  I personally don't recommend this, as the parameter name normally has some documentation about its purpose in its name (even if it is not to be used, as you can call it `dumb` or `unused`, see below), so with a single view to the prototype you can guess what it is used for.
- The second is more elaborate, you can avoid to name an unused parameter (C doesn't allow to use unnamed parameters in the implementation, just in prototypes, while C++ uses unnamed parameters in implementations to signal that the parameters are not used, but required by the function interface --the caller has to provide a value)  In C++ the situation is different: The thing is that, suppose you have to implement some function that has to implement a prefixed interface, but the implementation doesn't need to use one or more of those parameters.  If you name the unused parameter, you'll probably get a compiler warning as you declare a parameter that later you don't use.  Even worse, if you name it, and inadvertidly use it inside the function, you'll get valid code but erroneous (as that parameter was not to be used) so it would be better to get an error about some undeclared variable, if you try to use it.  But this is C++ stuff and the question was tagged C, so I'll not extend more on it.